# Python googlemaps, GoogleMapsError: Error 610: G_GEO_BAD_KEY

Tags: python, google-maps, server-side, api-key

I've got a problem with Python googlemaps. I've already generated api-key for server app in API Console, but I'm still getting error 610 when I'm running this part of code:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps

....

gmap = GoogleMaps(maps_api_key)
my_address = gmap.latlng_to_address(lat, lng)
```

Error:

```
raise GoogleMapsError(status_code, url, response)
GoogleMapsError: Error 610: G_GEO_BAD_KEY
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Looks like whatever library you are using might be using the deprecated v2 Geocoding Web Service.

Comment: It is possible, do you know any python google maps library for v3 api that supports something like Directions?

Answer (score 1):

Although Google deprecated the V2 calls with googlemaps (which is why you're seeing the broken calls), they just recently announced that they are giving developers a six-month extension (until September 8, 2013) to move from the V2 to V3 API. See Update on Geocoding API V2 for details.

In the meantime, check out pygeocoder as a possible Python V3 solution.